# Теряется качество изображения при записи и чтении из MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

Начал изучать MySQL и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Проблема такая. Есть два исходный файла, "Triss.jpg" и "Ciri.jpg". Их я записываю в базу данных MySQL из этих двух файлов, а потом загружаю из базы эти два изображения и записываю в файлы с такими же названиями, но в другой директории. Качество изображения теряется, не сильно, но все же. Заметил что исходный файл весит на 30-40 килобайт больше чем тот, что загружен в базе данных. Думаю что качество изображения теряется из-за этих 30-40 килобайт. Как записать файл без потери качества?

Вот код, который и делает все операции.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
        new Main().go();
    }

    void go() throws SQLException, IOException {
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "4826";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/learningdb"+
                "?verifyServerCertificate=false"+
                "&useSSL=false"+
                "&requireSSL=false"+
                "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false"+
                "&amp"+
                "&serverTimezone=UTC";

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName,  password)) {
            File imagePathCiri = new File("SourcePictures\\Ciri.jpg");
            File imagePathTriss = new File("SourcePictures\\Triss.jpg");
            addCharacterToDataBase(imagePathCiri, 20, connection);
            addCharacterToDataBase(imagePathTriss, 37, connection);
            File savePath = new File("LoadedPictures");
            loadCharacterFromDatabase("Ciri", savePath, connection);
            loadCharacterFromDatabase("Triss", savePath, connection);
        }
    }

    private void addCharacterToDataBase(File imageFile, int age, Connection connection) throws SQLException, IOException {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into witcherheroes (name, age, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, imageFile.getName().split("\\.")[0]);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, age);
        Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
        OutputStream outputStream = blob.setBinaryStream(1);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        preparedStatement.setBlob(3, blob);
        preparedStatement.execute();
    }

    private void loadCharacterFromDatabase(String name, File savePath, Connection connection) throws SQLException, IOException{
        int filePathSuffix = 1;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from witcherheroes where name = ?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()){
            String characterName = resultSet.getString("name");
            File saveFile = new File(savePath.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + characterName + ".jpg");
            while (saveFile.exists()){
                saveFile = new File(savePath.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + characterName + filePathSuffix + ".jpg");
                filePathSuffix++;
            }
            Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("image");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", saveFile);
        }
    }

}
```

Таблицу создавал вот такой командой:

```
create table WitcherHeroes (id mediumint auto_increment, name varchar(40), age int, image longblob, primary key (id));
```

Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста.

Comment: а может не стоит просто хранить изображение в БД?

Comment: БД никак не может менять размер изображения так, что бы оно при этом продолжало отображаться, но теряло качество. БД сохраняет набор байт как есть. Так что думаю это делает какой то из классов, которые вы используете для работы

Comment: В чем различие буферризованного изображения от нарисованного?

Comment: @Antonidas разница в 30-40 кб намекает на проблему с преобразованием перевода строк - в оригинальном файле было просто `\n`, а в результирующем стало `\n\r`. Проверяйте хекс редактором.